# how to print space between '*' in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to show a space after each `*`. My code is:

```
def stars(n):
    for x in reversed(range(n+1)):
            print x * '*'
```

The output I get is:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

But I want:

```
* * * * *
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
```

Also, I want to print from right side like

---

---

```
* *
  *
```

Is there any method to print from the last position?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to more easily join a sequence of letters with a given delimiter, in this case a space `' '`

```
def stars(n, delim=' '):
    for x in reversed(range(n+1)):
        print(delim.join('*'*x))

stars(5)
```

This gives

```
* * * * *
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
```

Answer (score 4):

When you multiply a string, it doesn't have to be a single character, you can use `print x * '* '`

```
>>> def stars(n):
...         for x in reversed(range(n+1)):
...                 print x * '* '
...
>>> stars(4)
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
*
```

Note that this will also show trailing space after each line; if this is problematic for you, you can use:

```
print (x * '* ')[:-1]
```

You could also import the print function that use the separator argument `sep`:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print(*('*'*4),sep=' ')
* * * *
>>> def stars(n):
...     for x in reversed(range(n+1)):
...             print( *(x * '*'), sep=' ')
...
>>> stars(4)
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
```